# Docker build and Github actions unable to prepare context: path "..."

Tags: asp.net, docker, github-actions

I've a weird issue with docker build in combination with GitHub actions.
The error I'm receiving is: `unable to prepare context: path "..." not found Error: Process completed with exit code 1.`

This error only occurs on the GitHub Actions, because when I run the same command locally on my laptop, it works fine.

```
  cd services/Gateway/OcelotGateway 
  docker build -f Dockerfile ... -t stanpanman/ocelotgateway:1.0.0
```

Are three dots not a thing inside the RUN command, i'm so confused?

My GitHub actions:

```
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: docker login
        env:
          DOCKER_USER: '${{ secrets.DOCKER_USER }}'
          DOCKER_PASSWORD: '${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}'
        run: |
          docker login -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD
      - name: docker build ocelotgateway
        run: |
          cd services/Gateway/OcelotGateway 
          docker build ... -t stanpanman/ocelotgateway:1.0.0
```

My Docker image:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Gateway/OcelotGateway/OcelotGateway.csproj", "Gateway/OcelotGateway/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Gateway/OcelotGateway/OcelotGateway.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Gateway/OcelotGateway"
RUN dotnet build "OcelotGateway.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "OcelotGateway.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "OcelotGateway.dll"]
```

[How my file structure looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs04W.png)

I've also tried to run the command:

```
  cd services/Gateway/OcelotGateway 
  docker build . -t stanpanman/ocelotgateway:1.0.0
```

But then I'm receiving this error:

```
 ---> Running in d12aaca83aeb
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat Gateway/OcelotGateway/OcelotGateway.csproj: file does not exist
Removing intermediate container d12aaca83aeb
 ---> cd903f3ffb15
Step 7/17 : COPY ["Gateway/OcelotGateway/OcelotGateway.csproj", "Gateway/OcelotGateway/"]
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I'm quite new with Docker, I expect that something isn't correct in my file structure. Help is really, really, really appreciated!

Comment: In the YAML file, use one dot `.` for the `docker build` directory path, the same as locally.  In the Dockerfile, the build context is already the `Gateway/OcelotGateway` directory (that same `docker build` directory) and so you don't need to include that prefix on the source path for `COPY`.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for your fast response. ` docker build ... -t stanpanman/ocelotgateway:1.0.0` Locally works via GitHub, it doesn't. I've also used `docker build . -t stanpanman/ocelotgateway:1.0.0` inside the GitHub action, but then it's not able to find .csproj. Or do I need to something inside my Dockerfile?

Comment: Got it fixed by running the command like this:
`cd services
          docker build -f Gateway/OcelotGateway/Dockerfile . -t stanpanman/ocelotgateway:1.0.0`